# How do I move a rectangle across a screen with SDL2.0 in C++?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm looking to move a square around another square using SDL. I'm looping through a series of values and rendering using the values as a position for one of my rectangles. I have another rectangle that is stationary, I'm currently re-rendering the stationary rectangle every time I loop, but I want to eliminate that as I know it's not efficient.

```
#include "render.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string FILE_NAME = "Orbit.txt";

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

const int SUN_LENGTH = 40;

const int EARTH_LENGTH = 20;

int main() {

    //Initialize SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                              "test",                   //title
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,   //initial x position
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,   //initial y position
                              WINDOW_WIDTH,             //width
                              WINDOW_HEIGHT,            //height
                              0                         //flags
    );

    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the case that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    ifstream file;

    file.open(FILE_NAME);

    //Prepare render loop
    string trash;
    string time;
    double xPos;
    double yPos;

    int shorterEdge;

    if (WINDOW_HEIGHT < WINDOW_WIDTH) {
        shorterEdge = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    } else {
        shorterEdge = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    }

    int numPixelsAU = (shorterEdge/2) - (EARTH_LENGTH/2) - 5;

    SDL_Rect sun;

    sun.x = ((WINDOW_WIDTH/2) - (SUN_LENGTH/2));
    sun.y = ((WINDOW_HEIGHT/2) - (SUN_LENGTH/2));
    sun.w = SUN_LENGTH;
    sun.h = SUN_LENGTH;

    SDL_Rect earth;

    //Render loop
    while (file >> trash >> time >> trash >> xPos >> trash >> yPos) {
        //Clear previous render
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        //Render Sun
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &sun);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &sun);
        //Render Earth
        earth.x = ((sun.x + (SUN_LENGTH/2)) + (numPixelsAU*xPos) - (EARTH_LENGTH/2));
        earth.y = ((sun.y + (SUN_LENGTH/2)) - (numPixelsAU*yPos) - (EARTH_LENGTH/2));
        earth.w = EARTH_LENGTH;
        earth.h = EARTH_LENGTH;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 30, 144, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &earth);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &earth);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(50);
    }

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is how should you calculate the position of earth in order to make an orbit around the sun?

You will have to calculate the posX and posY for each frame. Assuming each render takes 50 milliseconds (based on the SDL_Delay you used), if you want a full orbit to take 3 seconds you will have to make earth go pi/30 radians per frame. So your angle will start out at 0, then each frame add pi/30 to it.

posX = cos(angle) * radius

posY = sin(angle) * radius

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer. I'm not worried about position, that's not the issue. The program works fine as is, but right now I'm rendering the sun each time I loop in the while loop. Is there a way to keep the sun rendered, but only change the earth when I loop?

Comment: Modern graphics hardware prefers to draw the whole scene rather than using something like dirty rectangles or the like for preserving a part of the screen.